# Return a 2D array from php to android

Tags: php, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get data from a database back to my android app to work some magic with it, but I can't seem to find a good way of doing so. The most successful way so far has been to send a long, really long, string with every data separated by a specialsign. This didn't work since it could happen that the special sign got used in one of the datas and then everything would fall.

Now I managed to cram one row into an array, but I need to be able to put several rows into it.
My php, for now only adds the last row into the array

```
<?php
    $host="HOST";
    $username="USER";
    $password="PASS";
    $db_name="DATABASE";

    $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $json = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'], $row['col6']);

        }
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
?>
```

Comment: $json[] = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'], $row['col6']);

Comment: In your while loop try `$json[] = ...`. Also, $host etc don't need "" around them, and do not use mysql_* functions any more, they're (being?) depreciated. Use either mysqli_* or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote it, only the last $row is being stored, yes. To create a new array every time, simply add `[]` after `$json`. It will create a new sub-array for each row :

```
 $json[] = array($row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3'], $row['col4'], $row['col5'], $row['col6']);
```